# Bullet movement not working as expected when player sprite is moving

Tags: python, pygame

My game is a top down shooter. When the player is stationary and is shooting in any direction, the bullet goes in the same direction as the mouse. However, when I move diagonally whilst shooting the bullet is no longer in the direction of the mouse position. So basically it works when the player is stationary, but not when I'm moving.

Edit: I will keep trying to fix this but here is a video to better understand the issue https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyrTf.jpg

Here is the code:

```
import pygame
from sys import exit
import math

pygame.init()

# window and text
WIDTH = 1280 
HEIGHT = 720
FPS = 60

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('Shooting problem demo')
game_font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 50)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# loads imgs
background = pygame.image.load("background/gamemap.png").convert()
plain_bg = pygame.image.load("background/plain_bg.png").convert()

bullet_img = pygame.image.load("bullets/bluebullet.png").convert_alpha()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load("handgun/move/survivor-move_handgun_0.png").convert_alpha()
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotozoom(self.image, 0, 0.35)
        self.base_player_image = self.image

        self.pos = pos
        self.base_player_rect = self.base_player_image.get_rect(center = pos)
        self.rect = self.base_player_rect.copy()
 
        self.player_speed = 10 # was 4
        self.shoot = False
        self.shoot_cooldown = 0        

    def player_turning(self): 
        self.mouse_coords = pygame.mouse.get_pos() 

        self.x_change_mouse_player = (self.mouse_coords[0] - (WIDTH // 2))
        self.y_change_mouse_player = (self.mouse_coords[1] - (HEIGHT // 2))
        self.angle = int(math.degrees(math.atan2(self.y_change_mouse_player, self.x_change_mouse_player)))
        self.angle = (self.angle) % 360 

        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.base_player_image, -self.angle)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.base_player_rect.center)

    def player_input(self):   
        self.velocity_x = 0
        self.velocity_y = 0

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
            self.velocity_y = -self.player_speed
        if keys[pygame.K_s]:
            self.velocity_y = self.player_speed
        if keys[pygame.K_d]:
            self.velocity_x = self.player_speed
        if keys[pygame.K_a]:
            self.velocity_x = -self.player_speed
            
        if self.velocity_x != 0 and self.velocity_y != 0: # moving diagonally
            self.velocity_x /= math.sqrt(2)
            self.velocity_y /= math.sqrt(2)

        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            self.shoot = True
            self.is_shooting()        
        else:
            self.shoot = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                self.shoot = False

    def move(self):
        self.base_player_rect.centerx += self.velocity_x
        self.base_player_rect.centery += self.velocity_y
        self.rect.center = self.base_player_rect.center 
        
    def is_shooting(self):
        if self.shoot_cooldown == 0 and self.shoot:
            self.bullet = Bullet(self.base_player_rect.centerx, self.base_player_rect.centery, self.angle)
            self.shoot_cooldown = 20
            bullet_group.add(self.bullet)
            all_sprites_group.add(self.bullet)
                
    def update(self):         
        self.player_turning()
        self.player_input()    
        self.move()

        if self.shoot_cooldown > 0: 
            self.shoot_cooldown -= 1

class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, angle):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = bullet_img
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotozoom(self.image, 0, 0.1)
        self.image.set_colorkey((0,0,0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (x, y)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.speed = 10
        self.angle = angle
        self.x_vel = math.cos(self.angle * (2*math.pi/360)) * self.speed
        self.y_vel = math.sin(self.angle * (2*math.pi/360)) * self.speed
        self.bullet_lifetime = 750 
        self.spawn_time = pygame.time.get_ticks() 

    def bullet_movement(self): 
        self.x += self.x_vel
        self.y += self.y_vel

        self.rect.x = int(self.x)
        self.rect.y = int(self.y)
        if pygame.time.get_ticks() - self.spawn_time > self.bullet_lifetime: 
            self.kill()

    def update(self):
        self.bullet_movement()

class Camera(pygame.sprite.Group): 
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.offset = pygame.math.Vector2()
        self.floor_rect = background.get_rect(topleft = (0,0))  

    def custom_draw(self): 
        self.offset.x = player.rect.centerx - (WIDTH // 2) 
        self.offset.y = player.rect.centery - (HEIGHT // 2)

        #draw the floor
        floor_offset_pos = self.floor_rect.topleft - self.offset
        screen.blit(background, floor_offset_pos)

        for sprite in all_sprites_group: 
            offset_pos = sprite.rect.topleft - self.offset
            screen.blit(sprite.image, offset_pos)
     
# Groups

all_sprites_group = pygame.sprite.Group()

player = Player((900,900))
all_sprites_group.add(player)
bullet_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
camera = Camera()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
    
    screen.blit(plain_bg, (0,0))
    camera.custom_draw()
    all_sprites_group.update()    
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: So the problem is when I hold space (shoot) it drifts off to the wrong angle but when I let go of space it corrects the angle and goes in the correct direction

Comment: Actually there is not problem if you start the bullet at the position of the player: ` Bullet(self.base_player_rect.centerx, self.base_player_rect.centery, self.angle)`. It is just an optical illusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there is no problem at all. It is just an optical illusion. The projectile does not move relative to the player, but relative to the camera. The player is always in the center of the screen, because the player doesn't move, but the camera does. When the camera moves, all objects move with the camera.
For example, if you shoot a bullet to the right and move the player up, it will look like the bullet is moving diagonally to the right and down. To the right because it changes position, to the right and down because the player moves upwards.

To illustrate this, I reduced the speed of the player (`self.player_speed = 2`) and the speed of the bullet (`self.speed = 4`) and drew the scene on a checkered background:

[image]

---

`if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:` only makes sens in the event loop, but not in `player_input`. Shooting only one bullet at once just needs another condition (`and not self.shoot`):

```py
if keys[pygame.K_SPACE] and not self.shoot:
    self.shoot = True
    self.is_shooting()        
else:
    self.shoot = False
```

Comment: @juba1029 Actually there is not problem.  It is just an optical illusion. Answer changed.